# How to add External Dependencies to a PHP project?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

While trying out the VSCode on my PHP projects, I couldn't find an option/setting/extension that would allow me to add an external library and show any autocomplete tips based on the included code.
This feature is present in PHPStorm out of the box.

Am I missing something or VSCode really doesn't support this yet?

Comment: Intellisense is working for the basic PHP functions and the functions present on the project code. It doesn't work for external libraries that need to be included in the project as an external library.

Comment: nope, this is the language server used by php intellisense. and I couldn't find a way to import external files or folders.

Answer (score 3):

To add an external dependency you can use the VSCode multiroot workspace feature.

> The File > Add Folder to Workspace... command brings up an Open Folder
>   dialog to select the new folder.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_adding-folders

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with files included via server's config / .htaccess: `php_value auto_prepend_file mylibrary.php`